# Object of type <Model> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I have GFK like inheritance models of `Assets` (`Asset.model` having an asset_id, asset_name, and an `Account`, OneType.model, SecondType.model, all inheriting from the `Asset` model etc... based on [this](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/#alternative-2-intermediate-table-with-nullable-fields)), and I want to provide an API endpoint for all assets in my `Account`, I could have (not sure if this is convention) a property on the `Account` model that is a list that extends the different asset types:

```
#Account model
@property
def assets(self):
    assets = []
    assets.extend(self.onetype_set.all())
    assets.extend(self.secondtype_set.all())
    …
    return assets
```

I would need a serializer for the account

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # filter to assets for the user
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Account.objects.filter(organization=self.request.user)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('assets', )
```

and I assume for each of the asset types

```
class OneTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OneType
        fields = ('asset_id', 'asset_name',)
class SecondTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    …
…
```

but I keep getting an error: `Object of type 'OneType' is not JSON serializable` ( i understand the error means I need to get the model to be serialized into JSON, but I thought the model would call the model’s serializer….)

The stack trace doesn’t seem to be helpful because of the internal workings of DRF’s Viewsets, but here it is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in default
            else:
                return list(iterable)
            # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
    """
    raise TypeError("Object of type '%s' is not JSON serializable" %
                    o.__class__.__name__) ...
def encode(self, o):
    """Return a JSON string representation of a Python data structure.
    >>> from json.encoder import JSONEncoder
    >>> JSONEncoder().encode({"foo": ["bar", "baz"]})

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
o           <OneType: AssetName - Type 1 : Account 2>
self        <rest_framework.utils.encoders.JSONEncoder object at 0x11dce1668>
```

Viewsets.py:

```
class AssetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`, `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    serializer_class = AssetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOrganizationMember,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return Account.objects.filter(slug=slug)
```

Also, is this more of a DRF problem (I am not using a correct queryset) or a python problem (i am not providing a serializable method/class for the object/class)?

Comment: This is clearly a DRF problem, though I don't remember at the time what would be the correct code for this.  I guess you need to assign `assets = ...` in your AccountSerializer class, but instead of `...` there probably should be some magic polymorphic serializer which would apply the correct serializer for each element of the list.

Comment: Note that declaring `OneTypeSerializer` with `model = OneType` in its Meta does not automatically enable serialization of `OneType` with this serializer in all places.

Comment: Also take a look at [DRF docs on nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).  As you can see in the example, the serializer for a child field must be explicitly declared on the parent.

Comment: @chris Frisina seems like you are trying to return a **`OneType`** instance from the view class/view function. So, check the view or add the corresponding view

Comment: You'll need to provide your view code in order to get more helpful responses

Comment: @JPG, They are all basic class based.

Comment: The code snippets here don't show how the assets are supposed to be serialized. Not much we can do to help here.

Comment: @Linovia, actually I got it working by doing the following on the Account serializer assets = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)` hinted at from Mikhail's notes, but I think there might be other ways, maybe with different architectectures given different approaches to GFK like problems.   Stay positive!